# Using System.Threading.Thread.Sleep() in a Console app

Tags: c#, .net, system.thread

I'm working on a legacy console app (.NET Framework 4.7.2) for a client, its poorly written which is why I'm tasked with fixing it. He has this in his code in a couple places:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(someIntervalMillis);
```

At first I rolled my eyes because that's one of the most abused features in C#. But then when I considered what the app did it made more sense. Basically the app is only permitted to execute at certain times (midnight to 8AM) when it fetches some data from an API in chunks (due to API throttling, you can only make a request every 20 mins).

So the way he has it coded is that if its not between midnight-8AM then he does Thread.Sleep() until that time. Then he runs his API call and then Thread.Sleep(20 * 60 *1000); to wait for the throttling to reset then makes his next API call.

There's nothing else for the app to do during this period, its not taking other requests for anything, it just needs to wait till its time to execute so this code isn't blocking anything else from happening. If you tried to do it with a Timer, the console app would just exit after setting up the timer so it got me thinking, maybe this is not a bad way to do it for this particular scenario.

Is there a better way to do this or did I finally stumble on a non abused use of Thread.Sleep()? Thanks

Comment: Seems like this should either be a Windows service or a Console app that gets run at the appropriate time via a Scheduled Task. If it is going to be a Console app that runs all the time though, sleeping seems to be as good an option as there is. If it was run via a Scheduled Task, you'd still need to use the sleep between the API calls as I'm not aware of anything better.

Comment: @jmcilhinney its run on-demand by the client and once its done making its calls it just closes out until the next time they need it, not really anything they would schedule

Comment: So the user runs it when they want to but, if it's outside of that 8-hour window, it just sits there until midnight and then does the work?

Comment: Yep, its kinda odd, I know but that's how they want it